# did some one know how can i crop face after recognize it using google_mlkit on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

hello i have problem im working in a preoject that recognize face from gallery image and crop the face to return cropped face as new image
i read all questions in stackoverflow but the results very old its not working with the new version of flutter , and google_mlkit

```
Future<File> cropImageToFace(File image) async {
 final path = image.path; final FaceDetector _faceDetector = 
FaceDetector( options: FaceDetectorOptions(
 enableContours: true, ));
 final imageBytes = await image.readAsBytes();
 final imageList = <int>[];
 imageList.addAll(imageBytes); 
final imageData = InputImage.fromFile(image);
 print(imageData.filePath); 
print(imageData.inputImageData!.size); 
final faces = await _faceDetector.processImage(imageData);
if (faces.isNotEmpty) {
  final face = faces.first;
  final faceRect = face.boundingBox;
  final cropRect = Rect.fromLTRB(
      faceRect.left - (224 - faceRect.width) / 2,
      faceRect.top - (224 - faceRect.height) / 2,
      faceRect.left + (224 + faceRect.width) / 2,
      faceRect.top + (224 + faceRect.height) / 2);
  final croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
      sourcePath: image.path,
      cropStyle: CropStyle.rectangle,
      aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
      compressQuality: 100,
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
          toolbarTitle: 'Crop It'),
      iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          minimumAspectRatio: 1.0, aspectRatioLockEnabled: true));
  return croppedFile!;
} else {
  throw Exception('No face found in the image');
}
```

}

Comment: So, what is the problem? Could you be more specific? Also, you don't seem to use `imageBytes` and `imageList`, so you could just remove them.

Comment: yes i removed them 
 the problem here is the function return null 
the detection working fine but the problem is in crop